# Success of a PHP PDO Update Execute Statement When no Change to the Underlying Data Has Been Made

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP MySQL PDO statement that returns the correct `$retval = $stmt->rowCount();` when the underlying data is changed, but if no data is actually changed (for example all the fields are the same as the submitted data) then `$retval = $stmt->rowCount();` will return zero which makes success very difficult to determine.

Is there any way around this issue?

```
    try {
        $sql= "UPDATE project_phases SET allocated_cost = '$allocated_cost',allocated_hours = '$discover_hours', start_date ='$discover_startdate', end_date = '$discover_enddate', ";
        $sql = $sql. " architecture_hours ='$discover_hours_arch', interiordesign_hours='$discover_hours_id', artefacts ='$discover_artefacts'";
        $sql = $sql . " WHERE project_ID = '$project_ID' AND phase_ID = '$discover_ID'";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $retval = $stmt->rowCount();

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: How do you define 'success'?

Comment: Good point.  I think you are assuming that if there is no exception then it was successful.   Is that a sound assumption?

Comment: Problem is that 0 rows updated may mean there was no matching row or the row already contains the same data.  If your sure the row must exist, then it must be the second case.

Comment: Yes, I am sure the row exists as I have checked before using an UPDATE.  So I think I can do as you suggest.